# Laravel shows error displaying notification data

Tags: laravel, notifications

this is my code

in the app.blade.php, i added this code to the navbar. The count method is working fine. I just can't display the notification data value.

```
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-comments">Business Alerts</i>
              <span class="badge badge-danger navbar-badge">{{ count(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications) }}</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
              @foreach (auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
                <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                  {{--<i class="fas fa-info mr-2 green"></i>{{ $notification->type }}--}}
                  @include('layouts.partials.notification.'.snake_case(class_basename( $notification->type )))
{{ $notification->data['user']['email'] }}//it works only if i remove this line
                </a>
              @endforeach
                  
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a href="#" @click="$router.push('business_alerts')" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">See All Messages</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
@endforeach
```

In the browser i'm getting this

`Undefined index: alert (View: C:\laragon\www\test\resources\views\layouts\partials\notification\test.blade.php)`

when i try

`dd( $notification->data['alert']['id'] )`

it display `2`

this is the controller code

````
public function store(Request $request)
    { 
        $user = User::find($request['user_id']);
        $alert = ProductAlert::findOrFail($request['alert_id']);
        $alert->alert_qty -= $request['alert_qty'];
        $alert->save();
        $user->notify(new StockEpuise(json_decode($alert)));
        return invest::create([
          'alert_id' => $request['alert_id'],            
          'user_id' => $request['user_id'],            
          'alert_type' => $request['alert_type'],            
          'alert_qty' => $request['alert_qty'],            
        ]);
    }```

I don't know what is the problem
````

Comment: first dd($notification) and check what you get.i think it odesnt have alrert index

Comment: Can you provide more code ? Does the $notification come from a loop ? The first one may have a alert index while the second does not.

Comment: dd($notification) output ` #attributes: array:8 [
    "id" => "0238fe65-7530-456b-871b-542574dea1f3"
    "type" => "App\Notifications\StockEpuise"
    "notifiable_type" => "App\User"
    "notifiable_id" => 1
    "data" => "{"alert":{"id":2,"alert_type":"acht","alert_qty":0,"etat_alert":"Termin\u00e9","produit_id":2,"user_id":1,"created_at":"2021-05-24 12:10:25","updated_at":"2021-05-27 09:53:42"},"user":{"id":1,"name":"noia","brand":null,"email":"noia@e.com","type":"adin","photo":"profil.png","email_verified_at":nul,"created_at":"2021-05-24 11:35:23","updated_at":"2021-05-24 11:35"}}"
 `

Comment: @JohnLobo I think the alert index is: 2 and dd( $notification->data['alert']['id'] ) display it